# Why does giving list items "display: inline-block" make the bullets go away, and can I get around this?

Tags: html, css

I come before you to humbly ask for your wisdom.

In my work I often need to put lists into 2 or more columns. What I do is something like the following.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="mylist">
    <li>Here's a list item</li>
    <li>Here's a list item</li>
    <li>Here's a list item</li>
    <li>Here's a list item</li>
    <li>Here's a list item</li>
    <li>Here's a list item</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
#mylist { width: 400px; padding: 10px; border: 1px dashed #000; list-style: disc;}
#mylist > li { display: inline-block; width: 40%; max-width: 40%; margin-right: 5%; margin-bottom: 5%;}
```

Which, for some reason, doesn't display the bullets. Proof: http://jsfiddle.net/cLyebdof/

I've always resorted to hacks like adding `#mylist > li:before { content: "\002022"; text-align: -12px; padding-right: 12px; }` and other such garbage. But is there a better way?

Comment: Consider using `column-count:2` - removes the need for any hacks. [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cLyebdof/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These bullets appear only with `display: list-item` (default value for `<li>`). `display-list` property from [this](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#propdef-display-list) CSS3 draft will allow you to generate bullets for inline-blocks but it doesn't work yet in any browsers; so you should use `::before` pseudo-element or Chris Herbert's solution with `column-count`.

Answer (score 3):

Column-count is the way to go.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cLyebdof/7/

Browser support: http://caniuse.com/#feat=multicolumn (~92% of users worldwide)

#### CSS

```
#mylist {
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
    list-style-position: inside;
}
```

Comment: your solution does not work on most recent google chrome (bullets do not show), on IE11 only left column has bullets, and works fine on latest firefox. seeing how most people do not use firefox, your answer does not solve op's issue.

Comment: works after the `list-style-position: inside;` update

Answer (score 1):

Although you should use column count this, little hack should solve the problem.

```
#mylist {
    width: 400px;
    padding: 10px;
    border: 1px dashed #000;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#mylist > li { 
    float:left;
    width: 40%;
    max-width: 40%;
    margin: 0 2.5% 5%;
    list-style: disc outside none;
}
```

Comment: add `margin-left: 5%;` to your solution, as left column bullets are now shown

Answer (score 0):

instead of using display:inline for your li you can simply use

```
#mylist > li{
float:left;
}
```